# Computing $(AA\otimes BB + AB \otimes BA)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Can anyone suggest a way to numerically compute the following matrix vector product?

$$u=A^{-1}b=(AA\otimes BB + AB  \otimes BA)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(C)$$

Here $AA,BB,AB,BA$ and $C$ are  $d\times d$ matrices with $d\approx 1000$. A naive method is to expand Kronecker products and use linear solver for an answer in $O(d^6)$ time, but I need to do it in $O(d^3)$ time.

Not sure if helps, but $AA,AB,BA,BB$ are blocks of a covariance matrix, ie for partitioned random variable $(x,y)$
$$
\text{cov}\left(
\begin{array}{ll}
x\\y
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{cc}AA& AB\\BA& BB\end{array}\right)$$

I tried Jacobi-like iterative method, writing $A=M-N$ with $M=AA\otimes BB$ and $N=-AB\otimes BA$ and iterating $u=M^{-1}Nu+M^{-1}b$ which is cheap because of Kronecker products, but this sometimes diverges. Empirically, divergence seems to happen when $x$ and $y$ are highly correlated with each other. Any suggestions/literature pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Is $AB$ the product of $A$ and $B$ here (and similarly for $AA,BA,BB$), or are they just unusual names for four unrelated matrices?

Comment: They were unusual names, chosen to remember their locations in the covariance matrix. But it seems the same "convert to sylvester equation" approach works for either interpretation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$
(B^{-1}A)X + X(B^{-1}A)^T = B^{-1}A^{-1}CB^{-T}B^{-T},
$$
where $X$ is the matricization of $u$. This is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), which can be solved for $X$ in $O(d^3)$ time.

You'll get some numerical ugliness if $A$ or $B$ are close to non-invertible, but that might be unavoidable in some sense: if either of $A$ or $B$ are ill-conditioned then so is the original coefficient matrix $AA \otimes BB + AB \otimes BA$.

Comment: You can do it in $O(d^3)$ also without inverting blocks, by formulating it as a generalized Sylvester equation $AXB+CXD=E$: see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379587903144?via%3Dihub .

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed this connection! Matrices are singular, but I found good way to handle this in practice for this equation, similar to how pseudo-inverse handles singular matrices -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1a258310b266ac7ade35b025c9e6fae3